# Code review of cellForRowAt please in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a question about accelerating TableView.
I now write the following code in cellForRowAt.
However, I would like to lighter weight to handle it faster, can you give me advice?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell: BookListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(BookListCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BookListCell {
        let book = books[indexPath.item]
        cell.title.text = book.name
        if let image = book.image {
            cell.bookimage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            cell.bookimage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: image))
        }
        if let price = book.price {
            cell.price.text = String(price)
        }
        if let purchaseDate = book.purchaseDate {
            cell.bookDay.text = purchaseDate
        }
        cell.editButton.setTitle(R.string.setting.editButton(), for: .normal)
        return cell
    }
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You mean you want the code to run faster?

Comment: 1) Declare the properties in the Book class non-optional to get rid of the `if let` expressions. 2) Force unwrap `as! BookListCell`. The code must not crash. 3) Use an identifier constant rather than `NSStringFromClass`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Scriptable Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based. Also, the question in its current form is off-topic on [CodeReview.SE] too. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777 for more information.

Comment: Hi Zeta, thanks for the feedback. It was a suggestion, the title suggests the person is looking for a code review, which would point me towards codereview stackexchange, I mean.... its in the name?. I would expect the user to check once there if their question is on topic or not or whether it can be reworded or edit to do so. I personally dont think this question is a good fit here and I would expect the user to improve the question and post on code review. if not, whats the point in code review site? surely SO isn't the dumping ground/triage part of the exchange

Comment: @Scriptable Don't get me wrong: it's off-topic on SO, sure. However, the existence of another site isn't a valid reason to close it. We get a lot of users on [CodeReview.SE] that migrate from SO, just to get their questions closed and downvotes because they only got pointed to CR but not to the rules. Unfortunately, *"the user to improve the question"* isn't common :|. Yes, Code Review is for Code Review, but it isn't the dumping site for code either. For more information, see the link I already provided above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the link provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster unlikely to do, but you can make more beautiful for sure! :)

Try to share logic and comply with SOLID principles.

### CellForRow function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell: BookListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(BookListCell.self), for: indexPath) as? BookListCell {
        cell.configureWithBook(books[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

### BookListCell configure public function

```
func configureWithBook(_ book: BookModel) {
        title.text = book.name
        if let image = book.image {
            bookimage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            bookimage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: image))
        }
        if let price = book.price {
            price.text = String(price)
        }
        if let purchaseDate = book.purchaseDate {
            bookDay.text = purchaseDate
        }
        editButton.setTitle(R.string.setting.editButton(), for: .normal)
}
```

And also, if you create an object, such as a UILabel, then you should call it yourNameLabel.By analogy UIView - yourNameView. This is an unspoken rule.

All the best! :)

Comment: Always implement an `else` for any `if` statements for reusing table view cells. There are chances that the value is nil for the next object which will cause the cell to be still displaying value of the previous object. Either that or use nil coalescing operator.

Comment: Returning `UITableViewCell()` is nonsense. Force downcast the cell. The code **must not** crash if everything is hooked up correctly. If it does it reveals (immediately) a **design** mistake.